# HackerRank Bon Appétit problem failing two test cases

Tags: java

This is regarding the HackerRank Bon Appétit problem. I have written code using BigDecimal in Java. All test cases except two are failing and I am not sure why. The problem statement is that two people Bill and Anna are at a restaurant. Bill orders stuff which anna might be allergic to. So, for example if the bill amount array is [6,2,4] and anna does not have/avoids bill[2], the bill should be split such as (6 + 2)/2 if bill did it correctly. If Bill did not split the bill correctly, anna should get a refund at the end. For example if bill calculated it as (6 + 2 + 4)/2 = 16 and anna should get a refund of 4. If anna is charged the same amount as was calculated, you print "Bon Appetit" or else you print the extra amount that Anna was charged.

What I have done?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BonAppetit {

    // Complete the bonAppetit function below.
    static void bonAppetit(List<Integer> billList, Integer avoidedItemIndex, Integer chargedToAnna) {
        List<BigInteger> billListBigInteger = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Integer bill : billList) {
            billListBigInteger.add(BigInteger.valueOf(bill));
        }
        BigInteger avoidedItem = BigInteger.valueOf(billList.get(avoidedItemIndex));
        BigInteger annasCharge = BigInteger.valueOf(chargedToAnna);
        BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
        for(int i=0;i<billListBigInteger.size();i++) {
            if(i != avoidedItemIndex) {
                sum = sum.add(billListBigInteger.get(i));
            }
        }
        //Since there are only two people
        BigInteger split = sum.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
        if(split.equals(annasCharge)) {
            System.out.println("Bon Appetit");
        } else {
            System.out.println(annasCharge.subtract(split).intValue());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<Integer> billList = new ArrayList<>();
        File inputFile = new File("BonAppettitTestCase");
        if(!inputFile.exists()) {
            System.out.println("FIle not found, can't continue, exiting");
            return;
        }
        String line;
        BufferedReader fileBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        while((line = fileBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitNumberString = line.split(",");
            for(String number : splitNumberString) {
                billList.add(Integer.valueOf(number));
            }
        }
        bonAppetit(billList, 2814, 249990732);
    }
}
```

The test case which fails has the following numbers as shown in the attached file in the list. It contains 100000 numbers which is why I am attaching another file with this detail so that if you create a project to parse out the numbers, it will be easy for you.

The first argument to the bonAppetit function is the billList. I have created a comma separated list [comma separated list of numbers](https://gist.github.com/ashishraghavan/3522b280d4c50cb65db29856e6ba7bcb) so that you can add them to a list and use the same. The second argument is the index which Anna avoids to eat. The third argument is the amount that anna was charged. Other test cases are passing, but this one is failing and I don't understand why. Maybe BigInteger is not really required here, but I still used it. Please point me in the right direction in solving this problem for all test cases. The correct answer to this problem is 4009 Thank you!

Comment: For people who are downvoting, please give a reason as to why you are doing it. I will edit the question. Thank you.

Comment: Can somebody please tell me why am I being downvoted for this question? I posted the code, I posted the question as best I could. This is just discouraging learning programmers to post any such questions on StackOverflow in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't even know why you rushed to use BigInteger...

The problem is simple , count the sum then substract the unwanted food `k`, split it , if it equals to `b` then it's 'Bon Appetit' else he will refund her half the unwanted element `k` he overcharger her with.

something like this

```
    static void bonAppetit(List<Integer> bill, int k, int b) {
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<bill.size();i++){
        sum+=bill.get(i);
    }
    sum-=bill.get(k);
    sum=sum/2;

    if(sum==b){
        System.out.println("Bon Appetit"); 
    }else{
        System.out.println(bill.get(k)/2);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works with the solution you have provided. But, in the question, it was given that anna was charged 249990732. If I do the sum without including the item that anna avoided, then split the sum, then finally compare this split sum with anna's charged amount. If the split amount was equal to anna's charged amount, it is a "Bon Appetit" otherwise, anna gets a refund of a part of the charged amount. Shouldn't that also give the correct ?answer? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes you're correct |sum-b| is also correct , but the mistake is not there.
The mistake is this if statement

 (!aBillList.equals(avoidedItem)) {
                sum = sum.add(aBillList);
            }
You're not adding all the elements that have the same value as the avoided item which is wrong , that's why I added them all the elements , then subtracted the one we're avoiding  only once.

Comment: JadedBeast - you are exactly correct. I used  `if (!aBillList.equals(avoidedItem)) {
                sum = sum.add(aBillList);
            }` instead of `if(i != avoidedItemIndex) {
                sum = sum.add(billListBigInteger.get(i));
            }  ` which caused all the issues. I was comparing the avoidedNumber element instead of comparing the avoidedIndex. Thanks for pointing my mistake out. I have edited the original code with this correction and all test cases are passing.

Answer (score 0):

They have updated the problem on Hackerrank with more test cases that require you to use BigInt. Here's how I solved it:

```
function bonAppetit(bill, k, b) {
  let sum = BigInt(0);

  for (let i = 0; i < bill.length; ++i) {
    sum += BigInt(bill[i]);
  }

  sum -= BigInt(bill[k]);
  const anna = sum / BigInt(2);

  console.log(BigInt(b) === anna ? "Bon Appetit" : Number((BigInt(b) - anna)));
}
```